# clone should not work in child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a issue here...
There are two div first and second.I just cloned the first div which is draggable to the droppable second div. My requirement is to drag the cloned div also in the second div.The problem is the div in second ,when i drag also get cloned...

The code is

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.first').draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
    $('.second').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone());
            $('.second .first').draggable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove().clone();
                }
            });
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the clone and then check to see if that the dropped object has that class before cloning it again:

```
$('.second').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('clone')) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.clone().addClass('clone'));
            $('.second .first').draggable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove().clone();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SXT68/1/)

Comment: That was a fast downvote, explanation please - it answers the op question

Comment: @DaanHeskes Which one? Don't you think there are better sites than SO to play the kid?

Comment: @DaanHeskes Ok, i must be missing your inside joke :(

Comment: For the Same Question if i have to get $('.second .first').sortable() What should i do?

Comment: @user3024251 I think this should be asked as a separate question as I've never used sortable with draggable, sorry